# Not able to shift focus to Shipment Nbr field on Shipments screen

Tags: javascript, acumatica

I'm using the built in Acumatica browser commands to insert a new shipment record by pressing a function key. The function Key triggers the command with `px.searchFrame(window.top,"main")['px_alls'].ds.executeCommand("Insert");` For some reason, it triggers the insert command, but it doesn't shift the focus to the Shipment Nbr input field. Also, if you try to shift the focus manually using `var field=px_alls["edShipmentNbr"]; field.focus();` that doesn't work either. I've been able to shift the focus to other fields, so I know the code is correct, but I can't figure out why the focus can't be shifted to the Shipment Nbr input. Any ideas on what else can be done? It's not just the Insert command either. Calling the Cancel command, which should shift the focus, doesn't work either.

What's strange is that the Insert command can be called by pressing Ctrl+Insert, and it works perfectly.

I built some code that shifts the focus to the ship date field and then tabs backwards 5 times, which emulates correctly what the insert command should do, but it only works intermittently on the client's computer.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? And what is the reason to use JavaScript?

Comment: I just want to shift the focus to the Shipment Nbr field. It has to be Javascript because there's a listener on the keyboard key that the command is assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Acumatica Framework provides built-in support for keyboard shortcuts via the following properties defined in **PXButtonAttribute**:

- ShortcutShift = *true/false* : Determines Shift key presence
- ShortcutCtrl = *true/false* : Determines Control key presence
- ShortcutChar = *‘x’* : Determines shortcut character

Below is the sample to insert new Shipment when the user presses ***F2***. Since the code snippet below utilizes capabilities of the framework, by pressing ***F2*** the user executes the **Insert** command from the **SOShipmentEntry** BLC instead of simulating  button click in JavaScript. This approach guarantees that all logic embedded into the **Insert** command, including setting focus to the **Shipment Nbr** input, is properly executed.

```
public class SOShipmentEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
{
    public class PXInsertShortCut<TNode> : PXInsert<TNode> 
        where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
    {
        public PXInsertShortCut(PXGraph graph, string name)
        : base(graph, name)
        {
        }
        public PXInsertShortCut(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler)
            : base(graph, handler)
        {
        }
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = ActionsMessages.Insert, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
        [PXInsertButton(ShortcutChar = (char)113)]
        protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            return base.Handler(adapter);
        }
    }

    public PXInsertShortCut<SOShipment> Insert;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing a callback to the server in JavaScript, the callback return might set focus to another field after it finishes execution. Your focus() statement works but the callback return performs another focus() on a different control after yours.

Hooking the Ajax callback allows you to put your focus() statement after the Acumatica framework focus():

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { px_callback.addHandler(ActionCallback); });

function ActionCallback(callbackContext) {
   px_alls["edShipmentNbr"].focus();
};
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but if you try to do just the focus command, it won't work. This is the code that I want to work. If the user presses F9, it should shift the focus to the Shipment Nbr field. This doesn't work, so it must be something with that field and not the callback execution. `document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){if(e.keyCode==120){px_alls["edShipmentNbr"].focus();}});`