# How do I implement presskey event in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I want to call SmartPanel to popup by press any keys. 
Example: We click F3 in Selector Field. It'll popup search panel to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check my answer in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455496/not-able-to-shift-focus-to-shipment-nbr-field-on-shipments-screen/43462165#43462165)? You should have no problems utilizing PXButtonAttribute ShortcutChar property with an action opening popup.

For example, the following extension SOOrderEntry extension class will open Inventory Lookup on the Sales Order screen with the F2 key press:

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public PXAction<SOOrder> addInvBySite;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Stock Item", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXLookupButton(ShortcutChar = (char)113)]
    public virtual IEnumerable AddInvBySite(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        return Base.addInvBySite.Press(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no doubt your answer. This is what i'm look for . Thank you so Much!